# Merge two recursions recieving same parameter

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have two recursions which both receive the same parameter and are very similar in nature.

How can I merge them together and `return` an `object {}` with two properties, where each property holds the return of the recursion.

```
  function generateAbsoluteLevel(regItem) {
    if (!regItem.parent) {
      return regItem.level;
    }
    return Math.max(regItem.level, generateAbsoluteLevel(registryObject[regItem.parent]))
  }

  function generateAbsolutePath(regItem) {
    if (!regItem.parent) {
      return regItem.path;
    }
    return regItem.path.replace(/^/, generateAbsolutePath(registryObject[regItem.parent])).replace(/\/\//g, '/');
  }
```

In the end, I would like to receive something like

```
{
  path: '/src/tools',
  level: '100'
}
```

Comment: If it is a bad practice, please explain why. Thank you

Comment: Why do you want to merge? Do you mean to tie them together and get the results simultaneously?

Comment: @Akash, thank you. Basically, yes. Can I get the desired result using one recursion function, instead of two? As I said, the param is same for both functions.

Comment: What's `regItem`? Please share a [mcve] and explain what these functions do. Do they need to be recursive in the first place? Merging them means you lose generality on each distinct function so if you want to get level only without modifying the path (or whatever), you're stuck with the side effect/dependency on the path. Separation of concerns seems better offhand, without having more info. Thanks.

Comment: `regItem` is an object containing two fields, `path` and `level`. it comes from the loop on the array of `regItem` objects. recursion is a requirement in this task.

Answer (score 1):

While you *could* do something like this:

```js
function generateBoth (regItem) {
  if (! regItem .parent) {
    return {
      level: regItem .level,
      path: regItem .path
    }
  }
  const parent = generateBoth (registryObject [regItem .parent])
  return {
    level: Math .max (regItem .level, parent .level),
    path: regItem .path .replace (/^/, parent .path) .replace (/\/\//g, '/')
  }
}

const regItem = registryObject ['c']

console .log (generateBoth (regItem))
```

```html
<script>const registryObject = {a: {path: '//foo', level: 67}, b: {path: '//bar', level: 101, parent: 'a'}, c: {path: '//baz', level: 35, parent: 'b'}}</script>
```

I wouldn't recommend it.  Yes, perhaps you're saving some recursion steps, but the code is much, much more convoluted than this version:

```js
function generateBoth (regItem)  {
  return {
    path: generateAbsolutePath (regItem),
    level: generateAbsoluteLevel (regItem)
  }
}

const regItem = registryObject ['c']

console .log (generateBoth (regItem))
```

```html
<script>
  function generateAbsoluteLevel(regItem) {if (!regItem.parent) {return regItem.level;} return Math.max(regItem.level, generateAbsoluteLevel(registryObject[regItem.parent]))}
  function generateAbsolutePath(regItem) {if (!regItem.parent) {return regItem.path;}return regItem.path.replace(/^/, generateAbsolutePath(registryObject[regItem.parent])).replace(/\/\//g, '/');}
  const registryObject = {a: {path: '//foo', level: 67}, b: {path: '//bar', level: 101, parent: 'a'}, c: {path: '//baz', level: 35, parent: 'b'}}
</script>
```

So unless you've tested this for performance, and determined that this is an important bottleneck in your application, I would not bother.  Use the simpler code instead.

Answer (score 1):

If they are so similar in nature, you can factor out the common parts and abstract them into a function:

```
function makeGenerateAbsolute(prop, combine) {
  return function generateAbsolute(regItem) {
    if (!regItem.parent) {
      return regItem[prop];
    }
    return combine(regItem[prop], generateAbsolute(registryObject[regItem.parent]))
  };
}
const generateAbsoluteLevel = makeGenerateAbsolute('level', Math.max);
const generateAbsolutePath = makeGenerateAbsolute('path', (path, acc) =>
  path.replace(/^/, acc).replace(/\/\//g, '/')
);
```

You can also make it even more generic

```
function makeGenerateAbsolute(get, combine) {
  return function generateAbsolute(regItem) {
    if (!regItem.parent) {
      return get(prop);
    }
    return combine(get(prop), generateAbsolute(registryObject[regItem.parent]))
  };
}
const generateAbsoluteLevel = makeGenerateAbsolute(item => item.level, Math.max);
const generateAbsolutePath = makeGenerateAbsolute(item => item.path, (path, acc) =>
  path.replace(/^/, acc).replace(/\/\//g, '/')
);
```

and then also compose both your functions into one:

```
const generateAbsoluteBoth = makeGenerateAbsolute(item => item, ({level, path}, acc) => ({
  level: Math.max(level, acc.level),
  path: path.replace(/^/, acc.path).replace(/\/\//g, '/'),
}));
```